# Socketexception was unhandled - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Im trying to get time from internet for my tool.

I got this one here from stackoverflow (it is in c#, converted it to vb).

```
 Dim client = new tcpclient("time.nist.gov", 13)
 Using streamreader = new streamreader(client.getstream())
    dim response = streamreader.readtoend()
    dim utcdatetimestring = response.substring(7, 17)
    dim localdatetime = datetime.parseexact(utcdatetimestring, "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", cultureinfo.invariantculture, datetimestyles.assumeuniversal)
 End using
```

Im getting a "a connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time..." error.

Comment: Well, yes, because your computer is determining that the port is unsecure (well, it does on mine). Do you have access to a PHP-based webserver?

Comment: This code works for me, so it could be a firewall/proxy issue?